# getting Invalid json error when I am decoding below data using json_decode in PHP

Tags: php

[{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field phone\\",\\"field_value\\":0},{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field\\",\\"field_value\\":\\"test_zapier\\"},{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field select\\",\\"field_value\\":\\"1\\"}]

Comment: because it is invalid, you must remove `\\\`

Comment: Format your code. Take the [tour]. Read the [ask] guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `stripslashes` to remove `\\` and then decode

```
$data = '[{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field phone\\",\\"field_value\\":0},{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field\\",\\"field_value\\":\\"test_zapier\\"},{\\"field_display_txt\\":\\"New custom field select\\",\\"field_value\\":\\"1\\"}]';
  $json = json_decode(stripslashes($data), true);

 print_r($json);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a43301dddeb89aedca6a50eed703f935ac721496