# How to properly escape double quotes in a malformed json input before php json_encode

Tags: php, json, regex, escaping

I have a large json file that I'm importing before treatment. I do not control the content of this file, and the json is improperly escaped, leading to some cases of double quotes inside double quotes enclosed strings.
for example :

```
/...../
"productdiploma" : [],
"productcursus" : ["Méthodes"],
"productpublishedonsite" : false,
"productpublishedonkne" : false,
"productypologyparentality" : [ {
    "productmediaformat" : "01- Livre",
    "producttechformat" : "50- Grand format - "Autre"",
    "productparent" : ""
    }],
"productparentwork" : [ {
    "productparentworkid" : "1000248048",
    "productparentworktitle" : "TRAVAILLER EN FRANCAIS "EN ENTREPRISE" 2007"
/...../
```

In my import, the file is treated as a very large string with file_get_contents(). I probably need a preg_replace() or a preg_filter() there, but I can't quite figure what patterns I'd need to find and escape those double quotes with a \". Any Help/ideas out there ?

(and see comment below in anwser to shibon to see why it's not a duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting Invalid json error when I am decoding below data using json\_decode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022366/getting-invalid-json-error-when-i-am-decoding-below-data-using-json-decode-in-ph)

Comment: Maybe you should just report this to whoever is responsible for this file and ask them to fix the errors that are creating an invalid JSON String

Comment: @shibon : similar, but not duplicate. In the referenced question, the solution was straightforward, and the problem was entirely different, they add escaped enclosing quotes that it was easy to get rid of. Here I have double quotes within double quotes that I want to escape. I spent quite a while parsing the similar questions and answer before asking that one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Well that would be ideal, since it'd be much easier for them to provide a json to the specs than for me to correct the ugliness. Unfortunately their reaction time is about 3 weeks to change a comma in a file, and I must have finished that _way_ earlier that that :). I did report the bug to them and hopefully they will correct it, but I must deliver the result well before they'll have a chance to have corrected the problem. So I'm stuck with finding a way to correct their <censored expletive /> file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you need a different approach here. Loading the file as one large string means it's nearly impossible to know which double quotes are wanted and which ones are not. I'd go with an approach that allows you to read the fine line by line instead;

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  $line = fgets($file);
  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

This will allow you to test just the right hand side of each **:**, like this;

```
$partToTest = explode($line, ':')[1];
```

Knowing that for items that have quotes at all (i.e, not the arrays), they should be the first and last character on each line. So you could do something along the lines of;

*If the part has quotes, remove the first and last*

```
if($partToTest.substr($line, 0, -1) === "\""))
    $partToTest  = substr($line, 0, -1); # removes the last quote
    $partToTest  = substr($line, 1, 0); # removes the first quote
```

*Replace any remaining quotes with \"*

```
    $partToTest  = str_replace("\"", "\\\""); # escape remaining quotes
```

*Append and prepend new quotes to replace the ones we removed*

```
    $partToTest = "\"" . $partToTest . "\"";
```

*Put the line back together.*

```
    $line = explode($line, ':')[0] + $partToTest;
}
```

Admittedly, my php skills aren't the best so there may be a much simpler way of doing this, but the principle should work.

Comment: Hi Lewis. It's not a bad approach, a little heavy on the performance side I suppose, (the files as several hundred thousands lines) but that would be an effective way to address the problem. I was hoping for something more global, but, You're right, filtering the wanted from the unwanted is what had me stuck there. I suppose i'll end up doing it this way. :) Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. Yeah, I can see this being painful for datasets that large. Unfortunately I can’t think of another way to separate it.

Comment: I worked out some code based on your idea, see my reply below :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out this code, based on @lewis' idea :

```
$content = '';
while(! feof($infile) )
  {
    // reset line values at each iteration.
    $final_line = '';
    $test = array();

    // get the next line
    $line = trim(fgets($infile));

    // test if the line is splitable, else, white as is ({, [ etc...])
    if(strpos($line,'" : "')) {

        // split the line at quote+space+':'.space+quote to avoid splitting strings containing just ' : ' (not fool proof as a string might still contain '" : "' and split, but works in my case)

        $test = explode('" : "',$line) ;
        // add the final quote that we just stripped in the splitting to the key 
        $key =  $test[0].'"';

        // test if the line ends with a comma or not to decide at which position to remove the last quote 
        if( strpos($test[1], '",') == (strlen($test[1])-2) ){
            $val = substr($test[1],0,-2);
            $comma = ','; // store a comma for latter use
        } else {
            $val = substr($test[1],0,-1);
            $comma = '';
        }
        // no need to remove remove the fist quote it's been taken care of at splitting

        // replace the double quotes inside the trimmed string
        $val =  str_replace('"','\"', trim($val));
        // reassemble the corrected line
        $final_line = $key . ' : "' . $val . '"'. $comma ."\n";
    } else {
        $final_line = $line ."\n";
    }

    //store the line for later treatment
    $content .= utf8_encode($final_line);
  }
```

That does the job, though it's significantly slower, and there is still room for errors in the splitting if the line contains the '" : "' string inside the part I want to test, but that's a fix anyway :)